# How can I access data from a redis database in Mathematica?

Tags: databases

I have a program which writes data to a redis database and would like to visualize that data live in Mathematica. I only found DatabaseLink which seems to support only SQL databases. Is there a more direct way to do this than implementing my own C mathematica module?

Comment: I would try the java or C# clients. Using JLink or NETLink it should be possible to use these from within Mathematica...